# Partial derivatives with norms

Tags: multivariable-calculus

If we are workingin in $\mathbb{R}^n$ how can we compute the following expression: $$\sum_{j=1}^n \frac{\partial}{\partial x_j}\left(\frac{x_j}{\|x\|}\right)?$$

Do we express this as $$\sum_{j=1}^n \frac{\partial}{\partial x_j}\left(\frac{x_j}{\|x\|}\right)= \sum_{j=1}^n \frac{\partial}{\partial x_j}\left(x_j\|x\|^{-1}\right)$$ and use the product rule or is there a more efficient way?

Comment: I would be inclined to use the $\nabla\cdot (\phi v)$ formula but there's not much in it.

Comment: Think of $||x||$ as a simple function, namely $||x|| = \sqrt{x_1^2 + \dots + x_n^2}$. Then its derivative with respect to $x_j$ is $\frac{d}{dx_j} ||x|| = \frac{1}{2}(x_1^2 + \dots + x_n^2)^{-1/2}\cdot 2x_j = \frac{x_j}{||x||}$

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the case that $\lVert\cdot\rVert$ is the 2-norm, you have

\begin{align*}
\sum_{j=1}^{n}{\frac{\partial}{\partial x_{j}}\left(\frac{x_{j}}{\lVert{x\rVert}}\right)} &= \sum_{j=1}^{n}{\frac{\partial}{\partial x_{j}}\left(\frac{x_{j}}{\sqrt{\sum_{k=1}^{n}{x_{k}^{2}}}}\right)}\\
&= \sum_{j=1}^{n}{\left[\frac{1}{\sqrt{\sum_{k=1}^{n}{x_{k}^{2}}}} + x_{j}\frac{\partial}{\partial x_{j}}\left(\frac{1}{\sqrt{\sum_{k=1}^{n}{x_{k}^{2}}}}\right)\right]}\\
&= \frac{n}{\lVert{x\rVert}} - \sum_{j=1}^{n}{x_{j}\frac{x_{j}}{\lVert x \rVert^{3}}}\\
&= \frac{n}{\lVert x \rVert} - \frac{\lVert x\rVert^{2}}{\lVert x\rVert^{3}}\\
&= \frac{n-1}{\lVert x\rVert}.
\end{align*}

This isn't a different approach from yours, but it is a more concise expression for the sum.